# Vuejs : how to hide a component <div> on keyup escape?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Using Vue 2.5 I'm trying to hide a component if the `esc` key is pressed.

Inspired by [the documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers) on key modifiers, I wrote the following code but with no effect (for the moment I'm not hiding, just displaying a message):

```
Vue.component('my-component', {
    data: function () {
    return {isVisible:true,
    message:'no key pressed'}
  },
  template: '<div v-on:keyup.esc="myMethod" v-if="isVisible">This is my component<div>{{message}}</div>',
  methods:{
    myMethod : function(){
    this.message = 'esc key pressed'
    //My hiding action...
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  }
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzxugzo7/)

**EDIT** : looks like the issue is related to the fact I'm trying to implement this on a regular div, not on an input as it's usually used

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make static elements accessible to keyboard event use [tabindex](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/WD-WCAG20-TECHS/SCR29.html)

```
<div v-on:keyup.esc="myMethod" tabindex="0" v-if="isVisible">This is my component<div>{{message}}</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

I think you should add

```
created: function() {
  document.addEventListener('keyup', this.myMethod);
}
```

And in your method:

```
myMethod(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 27) {
    this.message = 'esc key pressed'
    console.log('esc key pressed');
  }
}
```

Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/uzxugzo7/9/

Also, don't forget to destroy it, to prevent memory leaks

```
destroyed: function() {
  document.removeEventListener('keyup', this.myMethod);
}
```

Comment: Your code will trigger any key pressed rather than ESC pressed.

Answer (score 4):

I would use something like

```
mounted() {
  window.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      * Note keyCode 27 is ESC
      // do stuff here
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to detect whenever the escape key is pressed anywhere inside the webpage, add an eventlistener to your application (not components) when your application is `mounted` (not `created`). For demonstration's purpose, I made use of `event bus` to show how the components receives the `escape-key-pressed` event.

(To test this snippet, click the output window first)

```js
Vue.component('custom-component', {
  template: `
    <div>
      <div v-show="show">
        Hide when Escape Key is pressed.
      </div>
      <button v-on:click="reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      show: true
    }
  },
  created() {
    window.eventBus.$on('escape-key-pressed', (val) => {
      this.show = false
      alert("escape key is pressed")
    })
  },
  methods: {
    reset() { this.show = true }
  }
});

window.eventBus = new Vue({})

const app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', this.handler);    
  },
  destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', this.handler)
  },
  methods: {
    handler() {
      // If escape key is pressed...
      if (event.keyCode == 27) { 
        window.eventBus.$emit('escape-key-pressed', true);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   Example
   <custom-component></custom-component>
</div>
```